# Live OGG streaming

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, stream, xamarin, ogg

I'm creating an iOS application in Xamarin.iOS (MonoTouch) and would like to connect to an OGG live stream and play it.
I've found the NVorbis library, but as far as I can see it doesn't support reading a live stream. And I'm also not really sure if this library is supported for Xamarin.iOS.
Same for the [csvorbis](https://github.com/mono/csvorbis) code, it doesn't seem to support live streaming.

I don't mind to change or create code to add support for live-streaming, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. Do I then to download portions of the stream and then play it, and doing this with every portion I download?

Of course I prefer an existing solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Tim,

NVorbis is my project.  While it doesn't currently support real-time protocols (RTSP & such), you might be able to use a NetworkStream instance with it successfully.  The decoder handles pages / packets as-needed, so it should work pretty well.

Please note, I haven't tested the forward-only Ogg reader logic in a long time, so there may be bugs...

Comment: ioctlLR, I've tried to do this myself, but I've no experience with the NetworkStream/Socket. Do you maybe have an example, or something that helps me getting started? I've to connect to an url like 'http://server-url:8000/tim.ogg'.   I've also seen the project is looking for Mono support. I've managed to get the project/test-app running in Mono on Mac. So finally I can help with this. Thanks!

Comment: @TimBrand: If I'm understanding your situation correctly, you might try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841974/how-to-read-the-response-stream-before-the-http-response-completes) for an answer.  If you are streaming over raw sockets, you'll have to create the NetworkStream from an already opened socket (IIRC).  I don't have any examples for that.