# Can not close StreamReader (reader.Close(); blocks code)

Tags: c#, .net, webclient, streamreader

I get  **continous** [ non-stop ] mesages from web url:

```
    string webUrl = "xxxxx/status.cgi";
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UUU", "PPP");

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(webUrl), Encoding.UTF8,true);
    string line;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if( line == "XXXXXX")
        {
           break;
        }
    }


    Console.WriteLine("Try to Close Stream Reader...");
    reader.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Stream Reader is closed...");
```

**The problem is that when I  break from while loop, i want to close the stream reader...But stream reader does not close...."reader.Close();" hangs/block the code...**

Why this happen? How to fix it?

UPDATE:
"using" DOES NOT WORK IN MY CASE: Exit the loop but stream reader is not disposed...Hang/Block

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestStreamReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string  webUrl = "http://X.Y.Z:7000/status.cgi";
            int counter = 0;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "000000");

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(webUrl), Encoding.UTF8, true))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        counter++;

                        Console.WriteLine("Input"+ line);

                        if (counter == 10)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("I am exiting the loop");
                            break;
                        }


                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Exit the while loop");

                }

                Console.WriteLine("Reader should be desposed");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Web Client should be disposed!");



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error or exception?  If so, what is it?

Comment: WebClient has no "close method"...But I do same for HttpWebResponse which has close method...Does not change anything...

Comment: I do not get any exception...When I debug  I CAN NOT PASS TO THE "Stream Reader is closed" line...It hangs/block

Comment: It has a dispose method. You can use it within "using"

Comment: Is the "reader.Close();" line being hit? To find out, put a breakpoint on it and hit F5.

Comment: Not work...I make also  a C++/CLI project in which I explicityly call "delete client"...then call reader close...Same happened...

Comment: I debug it guys...reader.close() hit...But web response is continous...Maybe this cause this...Because requested url sen message always...

Comment: @Novallis The Using statement will help you. I'm not sure if your code sample above compile? In regards of `Encoding::UTF8`.

Comment: It does not...It still blocks

Comment: Can your device take signals? Like if you send back a sort of "STR::IP <IP> STOP" in a separat thread. What kind of device are you recieve from?

Comment: Well, it is a DVR...It may take "signals" but it is not open to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using WebClient, have you thought about using HttpWebRequest and getting the response stream?

```
//using System.Net;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiProcedure.FunctionUri);
    request.Credentials = (CredentialCache)Credentials;
    request.PreAuthenticate = true;

    //define the type of request
    request.Method = HttpMethod;
    request.ContentType = "application/json";

    //execute
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
```

I know you're doing a continuous stream, but you should be able to treat the stream reader normally like you're doing in your example.  I think this method will give you a little more control.

I normally only use WebClient if I need to perform a simple task where all the nitty gritty setup/streams are done for me.  Find I get better results when managing the request and response separately.

Good luck!

EDIT: Also, this is just a snippet from my code. You might want to take a look here: [C# - How to read a continuous stream of XML over HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775574/c-sharp-how-to-read-a-continuous-stream-of-xml-over-http) for a good example of reading continuous chunks of data.

Comment: I try with HttpWebRequest and Response...and ReadToEnd also block since the data never ends...Does not work

Comment: @Novalis: Does the server that is sending the data have buffering disabled so that it will continuously stream the data?   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.buffer.aspx

Comment: Well, I do it with HttpWebRequest /HttpWebResponse...But instead of request.Close() i call request.Abort() Then I can able to close stream reader...I do not know why "close" not work but "Abort" work...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but none of the suggestions made in this thread were helpful for me.  But I WAS able to fix it a different way, so I thought I'd share...

I used the asynchronous version of `client.OpenRead(uri)` to open the stream, and then I was able to call `client.CancelAsync()` when I need to shut it down. The implementation in there must be disposing the `StreamReader` differently, because it works that way.

Answer (score 0):

A Quick idea frm my side, try put the StreamReader in a Using.

```
        string webUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UUU", "PPP");

            int counter = 0;

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(webUrl), Encoding.UTF8, true))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line == "XXXXXX")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    counter++;
                }

            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Try to Close Stream Reader...");
        Console.WriteLine("Stream Reader İSclosed...");
```

This will keep Connection open until it's no longer used. The Dispose() will be called automatically after then. No need of manual detach or close. [Update] I also move the WebClient into a using and the counter variable outside the StreamReaders using.

[Edit]
Due to comments the problem looks like a (untested speculation) side-effect of the WebClient can't quit, because it can't see the end of the stream. Therefore, the StreamReader wait. I attach Another approach to read from a webrequest. However this will far from sure work better.

```
    string webUrl = "http://www.google.com";

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webUrl);
    req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UUU", "PPP");
    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            int read;
            string line;

            byte[] data = new byte[4096];
            while ((read = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)) > 0)
            {
                line = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetString(data, 0, data.Length);

                if (line.Contains("(function(){try{var a=window.gbar;"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("End Bit founded..");
                    // Some more logic?
                    break;
                }
                data = new byte[4096];
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("End of Stream");
```

Please note I used Stream here and manually split to 4096 datablocks, just for the sake of the problem. The usual would be `using (StreamReader stream2 = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))  {  string test = stream2.ReadToEnd(); }`.

Hope it will give any step further.
Also mind that Encoding is set to "ASCII" above.

Comment: That will call Dispose at the end, which just calls Close.  It will result in the same thing.  Only difference will be it will be blocked *before* the first Console.WriteLine

Comment: @Peter Of course, it call Close() on Dispose(). Using let .NET take care of the life time.

Comment: @Novalis Can we have more information about your scenario. I.e. your endpoint (the .cgi url) can freeze your connetion or such. This code works excellent on 'regular' tests. Did you try your code to other URL's?

Comment: My url gives "continous messages" from cgi...Theoretically "infinite"...That makes  my scenariou unique"

Comment: @Novalis Indeed, though you have confirmed the code itself work? That's your particular URL who raise the problem. I'm not sure how to reproduce the environment make it fail the same. Perhaps if you try force-end WebClient would with `client.Dispose()` before the `break;`.

Comment: Not "particular" url...If you have a device/url which gives continous data from CGI interface...you can produce the same result.

Comment: Not the URI, but the data u recieve from it. I could be more clear. I edit the post with another approach, fetch it as a WebRequest. The stream will hopefully have better handling for such case.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar. The problem is that it's waiting for a ReadTimeOut to occur. You can try  setting the Stream.ReadTimeOut property to something sufficiently small.