# How to read into an XElement a continuous stream of XML over HTTP

Tags: c#, xml, http, streaming

I am receiving 'chunks' of xml over an http response stream. Each chunk is a complete mini xml hierarchy, such as:

```
<chunk1>
  <id>1</id>
  <data>blah blah-blah</data>
</chunk1>
...
(30 seconds later)
...
<chunk2>
  <id>2</id>
  <data>blah blah-blah</data>
</chunk2>
...
(30 seconds later)
...
<chunk1>
  <id>3</id>
  <data>blah blah-blah</data>
</chunk1>
```

What is the best way in c# to read each 'chunk' into an XElement for further processing? Each chunk may have a different root element.

I have seen responses to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775574/c-sharp-how-to-read-a-continuous-stream-of-xml-over-http). However, the responses did not seem optimal, as they involved processing each node. I just want to read the stream until I reach the closing node corresponding to the opening chunk node, feed the whole chunk into an XElement, call a method to process it, and then wait for the next chunk.

Comment: Reading the chunks into a `StringBuilder` or some list wouldn't suffice?

Comment: I would need to know when to stop reading (i.e., when the closing root element had been reached)?

Comment: Ohh, I see now. So its possible that a response chunk may contain partial chunk for next or previous chunks? If not (i.e. the chunk is always a single node), then things are bit easier.

Comment: IOW, are you expecting "<rootX>...</rootX>" in each chunk or can they be "rootX><rootY>...</rootY>" or "<rootX>...</rootX><roo"?

Comment: The response is a stream that (in theory) never ends.

Comment: So you may not even get a whole chunk in one read, right?

Comment: Correct, depending how you define "one read"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what I was looking for:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, new XmlReaderSettings() { ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment });

while (reader.Read())
{
  using (XmlReader subTreeReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
  {
    XElement xmlData = XElement.Load(subTreeReader);
    Process(xmlData);
  }
}
```